# Why compiler cannot infer the Box<T> pointer size

Tags: rust

I'm learning the state pattern in rust. I tried the following trait definition, it filed to compile.

```rust
trait State {
    fn review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>{
        self
    }
}
```

The error message is:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
4 |         self
  |         ^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = note: required for the cast from `Box<Self>` to `Box<(dyn State + 'static)>`
help: consider further restricting `Self`
  |
3 |     fn review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> where Self: Sized{
  |
```

Isn't `Box<T>` a smart pointer that implemented in struct. Shouldn't it have fixed size? My understanding is that it internally should hold a c like pointer that points to the actual heap memory.

The following train definition works. So if compiler really cannot infer size of `Box<T>`, then why would the following work?

```rust
trait State {
    fn review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
}
```

Comment: Please always post the _full_ error from `cargo check`, not part of it.

Comment: The pointer has a size known at compile time. It's the type inside the box the compiler is complaining about. Try `trait State: Sized` instead.

Comment: @SvenMarnach a `: Sized` trait isn't object safe so that won't work.

Comment: The way I interpret this error is, coercing Box<impl Trait> to Box<dyn Trait> conceptually involves dereference g it. This feel wrong, what is actually going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the error carefully. It does not say:

```
the size for values of type `Box<Self>` cannot be known at compilation time
```

Rather, it says:

```
the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time
```

And from the suggestion (suggesting to add `where Self: Sized`), we can conclude that the problem is that `Self` does not (or more correctly, *might* not) implement [`Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Sized.html). In other words, `Self` might be a [Dynamically-Sized Type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/dynamically-sized-types.html#dynamically-sized-types) (a DST for short), such as a slice or a trait object. It *does not* mean the compiler does not know the type size ahead of type (which is true for any trait definition); it means the type *does not have* a size known at compile-time.

And if `Self` is a DST, we cannot convert `Box<Self>` to `Box<dyn State>`. Why?

To answer this question, we need to understand how conversion from `Box<Type>` to `Box<dyn Trait>` in the general case works.

`Box<Type>` is a pointer to type, one machine word sized. It only contains the address of the data (ignoring stuff like CHERI).

But for `Box<dyn Trait>` this is not enough. How can we call methods of the type, if we don't know the type?

The answer is a [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). It contains the addresses of the trait's functions for the type, and it is attached (a pointer to it, to be precise) to the pointer to the data.

So `Box<dyn Trait>` is actually *two* machine words sized: one for the data pointer, the other for the vtable. In a similar fashion, `Box<[T]>` is two words sized, one for the data pointer and another for the slice length.

When you convert from `Box<Type>` to `Box<dyn Trait>`, we *attach* the vtable (in a process called *coercion*) to the data pointer, and from one-word-sized `Box`, we get a two-words-sized `Box`.

But what if our `Box` is *already* two words sized? For example, `Box<dyn Trait>`? We cannot get a three-words-sized `Box` because `Box<dyn Trait>` is always two words sized, and the caller is expecting the same. And we cannot just drop the inner vtable because then we won't know how to call the methods. So we're stuck, and we cannot do this (without allocating, which is always explicit in Rust).

And this is what the compiler says. If `Self` is a DST, such as a trait object, we cannot do this coercion, and so we always cannot do it because our code has to be correct always.

One solution, suggested by the compiler, is to add `where Self: Sized` to the method. This restricts it so it cannot be *called* with DSTs, which solves our problem.

Another solution is to implement `State` for `Box<T> where T: State` too, and then box the value *again*. A `Box<Box<T>>` is always a thin pointer (one machine word), even if `T` is a DST. This works even for DSTs. Of course, you can always override the default implementation in `Sized` types to use a more efficient non-`Box`ing approach.

Comment: So for a DST to work, the easiest way is to use Box<Box<T>>? This seems rather inconvenient and counter intuitive. What is the rationale for Box<dyn Trait> to be two word sized instead of three word sized?

Comment: @Dennis Yes (for the `Box<Box<T>>` for the DST). Why will `Box<dyn Trait>` be three words? It needs only two, one for the data pointer and one for the vtable. And it needs _some_ fixed size, so for example when you pass it to a function it knows what size to expect (known ABI).  And if it was three, it would still not allow you to coerce `Box<dyn Trait>` to `Box<dyn AnotherTrait>` _twice_, only once (because twice needs four words). So the simplest thing is to just make it to words, and disallow this coercion altogether.